# Search price between two values with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to send a curl request in order to display my result.
I try this URl on my localhost:

> localhost:9200/book/book/_search?q=title:wizard&price["10"TO"24"]&pretty=true

My request work, but in my result I see more book with a higher price to $24

if anyone can help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `AND` operation is different from `&` which is a query string key-value separator.

Try this instead:

```
localhost:9200/book/book/_search?q=title:wizard AND price:[10 TO 24]&pretty=true
```

Comment: I've obtain this error: 
  "error" : "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query]

Comment: this one worked on my case:

`localhost:9200/book/book/_search?q=title:wizard AND price:[10 TO 24]&pretty=true`

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
localhost:9200/book/book/_search?q=title:wizard AND price:[10 to 24]&pretty=true
```

HOpe it helps..!

Comment: can you post your sample data ??

Comment: yes, but replace "...wizard&price..." part with "...wizard AND price..."